# How to place a android webview in the real world using google tango?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-webview, google-project-tango

Android webview can be used as a UI element in Android, how do I render the whole webview at a specific place using Google Tango? Currently, one can place 3D objects, sprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but not with normal Android UI out of the box

If you build your tango application using unity you can use for example this https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/82379 to render the web view as part of the 3d space